# Usando API no React JS

Tags: api, react, axios, cors

Sou nova no ReactJS e estou aprendendo sobre API. Estou tentando utilizar uma API do Star Wars, mas não está me dando retorno. Já utilizei outras e deram certo.

Este é meu arquivo App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from './api';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    filmes: [],
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await api.get('films');

    this.setState({ filmes: response.data });

    console.log(this.state.filmes);
  }

  render() {

    const { filmes } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Listar os Filmes</h1>
        {filmes.map((filme) => (
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">{filme.results.title}</h2>
              <h3 class="card-episode">{filme.results.director}</h3>
              <h4 class="card-date">{filme.results.release_date}</h4>
              </div>
              </div>    
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

E este é meu arquivo api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://swapi.dev/api/'
});

export default api;
```

Este é o link da api: https://swapi.dev/api/films/

O erro que recebo é:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://swapi.dev/api/films' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
> at createError (createError.js:16)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
>
> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response
> was received.
>
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map:
> HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
>
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

No Firefox:

[image: Erro exibido no console do navegador]

Não sei o que fazer e como fazer para corrigir isso.

Comment: O [servidor](https://swapi.dev/api/films/) que está buscando os dados não suporta CORS e [o Axios restringe que transações fora da mesma origem ocorram sem os cabeçalhos CORS](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1358). Para obter esses dados em sua aplicação vai ter reescrever usando [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) no lugar do *Axios* usando o modo `no-cors`

Answer (score 1):

Você tem uma rejeição de CORS.

Verifique os headers da requisição e da resposta e veja se seu servidor.
O header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` é muito importante quando se trata de requisições por script, como a MDN diz:

> Por motivos de segurança, navegadores restringem requisições cross-origin HTTP iniciadas por scripts.

Garanta que o mesmo estará definido corretamente

Nos casos em que passei por isso, o que mais ocorria era:

- A falta do header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ou sua correta utilização.
- A requisição tinha como `Accept-Language` valores que o servidor não aceitava
- O método de requisição `options` não era aceito pelo servidor.

[Dê uma olhada nesse material da MDN, é essencial entender o que é o CORS e porque existe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS)

Answer (score 0):

O componentDidMount não precisa ser assíncrono, tente assim:

```
componentDidMount() {
 api.swAPI("films", "get", (response) => {
  this.setState({ filmes: response.data });
 });
}
```

No template verifique assim:

```
{filmes && filmes.length ? filmes.map((filme) => (
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">{filme.results.title}</h2>
              <h3 class="card-episode">{filme.results.director}</h3>
              <h4 class="card-date">{filme.results.release_date}</h4>
              </div>
              </div>    
        )) : (null)}
```

No seu arquivo de api tente assim:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = {
    swAPI(path, method, callback) {
        axios({
            url: `https://swapi.dev/api/${path}`,
            method: method,
        }).then((result) => {
            callback(result);
        });
    }
}

export default api;
```